# Convert count into length

Tags: macros, calculations, lengths

I want to decrease a length by a number (count). I tried some variations with `\newlength{\temp}` and `\addtolength` but I got problems there with the minus. I also tried variants with `\dimexpr`.

The following example is an absolute MWE. temp must be possibly negative. The mathematical operation must be a subtraction. Originally I had some `\expandafter`s in there, but they are probably wrong and mess up the readability.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}

\newcount\temp
\temp=-30

\def\haha#1{xyz \hspace{\advance\strip@pt#1 by -\temp pt} abc}

\haha{90pt}

\end{document}
```

The output should be

xyz-hspace60pt-abc

Comment: This *is* as simple as `\hspace{\dimexpr#1+\temp pt}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following achieves what you're after:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\newcounter{temp}
\setcounter{temp}{-30}

\newcommand{\haha}[1]{xyz-\hspace{\dimexpr#1+\value{temp} pt}-abc}

\haha{90pt}

xyz-\hspace{60pt}-abc% verification

\end{document}
```

I've used the LaTeX2e interface for counters, together with `\value{<cntr>}` to return a number of the counter `<cntr>`.

Comment: Aaaah. I just found out (inspired by yours), that this works also: `\def\haha#1{xyz \hspace{\dimexpr#1-\the\temp pt} abc}` This is a hybrid of two of my approaches.  And basically the same as yours.

Comment: @MaestroGlanz `\the` is redundant

Comment: In my, lets say guess, I put the dimexpr in front of the wrong value of both. No wonder....